# Show Panel which is inside UpdatePanel in ASP.Net using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Net and JavaScript guru, I have following code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
            <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="width:1200px;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtInd" Width="600px" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Wrap="true" ScrollBars="auto" Width ="1000" Height="400" >
                    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView2" OnClientNodeClicking="onNodeClicking"
                        NodeWrap="true" 
                        runat="server" 
                        ExpandDepth="0" 
                        PopulateNodesFromClient="false"
                        ShowLines="true" 
                        ShowExpandCollapse="true"
                        Visible="True"  OnTreeNodeExpanded="TreeView2_Expanded" OnTreeNodeCollapsed="TreeView2_Collapsed"
                            onselectednodechanged="TreeView2_SelectedNodeChanged" BackColor="#DEBA84" 
                            BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"  
                        Font-Size="Large">
                        <HoverNodeStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
                        <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                        <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" />
                    </asp:TreeView>
                </asp:Panel>

                <ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender BehaviorID="dde" ID="DropDownExtender2" 
                    TargetControlID="txtInd" DropDownControlID="Panel1" runat="server" >
                </ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender>
            </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
              <Triggers>
                 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TreeView2" EventName="SelectedNodeChanged" />
             </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   
     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
     function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
         var treeViewData = window["<%=TreeView2.ClientID%>" + "_Data"];
         if (treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value != "")
         {
             $find("dde").hide();
         }
         else
         {
             $find("dde").show();
         }
     }
</script>
```

What I want here is when + or - image button is clicked in TreeView keep Panel open. 
What my JavaScript code is doing now, it is keeping open Panel while TreeView is not selected. It is working fine while TreeView is not selected.
Whenever I select any node in TreeView, my code is not working because treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value != "" and Panel is being hided. 
How to rewrite my JavaScript code  to make it work even TreeView node is selected. Please help me, I could not find the way to solve this issue, thanks in advance.